# Matrix Calculator Tools

Tags: matrices, math-software, online-resources, calculator

Does there exist any such software/online calculator where I can enter a matrix and am able to obtain the formula for an arbitrary power of the matrix?

It would be an added benefit if the entries of the matrix are allowed to be variables.

In case this question belongs somewhere else, I would be glad to be pointed in the direction.

**Edit 1:** I would like to add more detail as to what my aim is. I have a set of matrices consisting of two variables $a \in \mathbb{N}, b \in \mathbb{R}.$ I want to know whether for infinitely many of them the $a^{\text{th}}$ power is positive.

Right now I'm just handpicking some matrices and checking for them to see whether this is true. I would be happy to be suggested better methods for the same.

**Edit 2:** The matrices are as follows:

$$A(a,b)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{a}{b}-1&-1&-1&-1\\
-1&\frac{a}{b}-1&-1&-1\\
1&-1&\frac{a}{b}-1&-1&\\
-1&0&-1&\frac{a}{b}-1\end{pmatrix};\ a\in \mathbb{N}, b \in \mathbb{R}$$

I want to check whether every entry of $A(a,b)^a$ is positive for infinitely many $a$ and $b.$

Comment: You could use Sage (Python-based open-source alternative to Mathematica etc.) at cocalc.org.  It can compute with symbolic variables.  If that sounds helpful I can give you some example code.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Unfortunately, I am supposed to deal with too many matrices at the moment and check something for all of them, guessing and proving a general formula for each of them would be too tedious.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Please check my edit. I tried explaining my task better.

Comment: You could include an explicit example of one such a matrix, so we see what you are up to. What do you mean by $A^a$ is positive? All coefficients are positive? So we are dealing with real numbers?

Comment: @DietrichBurde By positive I mean each entry is positive.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have added the matrix now too.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Wolfram Alpha.

The general syntax is matrixpower[matrix in matrix form, power] and below are examples.

Here is one with only [*numbers*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixpower%5B%7B%7B1%2C2%7D%2C%7B3%2C4%7D%7D%2C5%5D).

Here is one with [*variables*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixpower%5B%7B%7Ba%2C2%7D%2C%7B3%2C4%7D%7D%2C5%5D).

If you want to give a matrix $A$ and find $A^n$, you can also use this same approach and here is an [*example*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixpower%5B%7B%7B1%2C2%7D%2C%7B3%2C4%7D%7D%2Cn%5D).

When a matrix is diagonalizable, you can use $A^n = P D^n P^{-1}$ from the Jordan Normal Form.

You should also consider using some of the free CAS tools like SAGE or Python.

Of course, professional CAS programs have things like [*Mathematica - MatrixPower*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPower.html).

You can also consider a free cloud account on the [*Wolfram Cloud*](https://www.wolframcloud.com/), which gives you access to Mathematica commands, which are not all in Wolfram Alpha.

**Update**

$A^n(a, b) = \begin{pmatrix}
 \dfrac{-b n \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n+a \left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^n-b \left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^n}{a-b} & \dfrac{2 a \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-2\right)^n-2 b \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-2\right)^n-a \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n-a \left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^n+b \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n+b \left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^n+2 b n \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n}{a-b} & \dfrac{2 a \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-2\right)^n-2 b \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-2\right)^n-2 a \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n+2 b \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n+b n \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n}{a-b} & -\dfrac{b n \left(\dfrac{a-b}{b}\right)^n}{a-b} \\
 -\dfrac{b n \left(\dfrac{a-b}{b}\right)^n}{a-b} & \dfrac{2 a \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-2\right)^n-2 b \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-2\right)^n-a \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n+b \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n+2 b n \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n}{a-b} & \dfrac{2 a \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-2\right)^n-2 b \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-2\right)^n-2 a \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n+2 b \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n+b n \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n}{a-b} & -\dfrac{b n \left(\dfrac{a-b}{b}\right)^n}{a-b} \\
 \dfrac{b n \left(\dfrac{a-b}{b}\right)^n}{a-b} & \dfrac{-a \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-2\right)^n+b \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-2\right)^n+a \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n-b \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n-2 b n \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n}{a-b} & \dfrac{-a \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-2\right)^n+b \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-2\right)^n+2 a \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n-2 b \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n-b n \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n}{a-b} & \dfrac{b n \left(\dfrac{a-b}{b}\right)^n}{a-b} \\
 \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n-\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^n & \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-2\right)^n-2 \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n+\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^n & \left(\dfrac{a}{b}-2\right)^n-\left(\dfrac{a}{b}-1\right)^n & \left(-\dfrac{b-a}{b}\right)^n \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Now, you have to do cases based on $a, b$ to determine if things are positive. It may be easier to choose $a, b$ prior to taking the matrix to the $n-th$ power and seeing if you can determine it from that.

Comment: For matrices computation, Matlab is very good ; here you can have access to its free equivalent, Octave : https://octave-online.net/

Comment: @JeanMarie: I don't use Matlab/Octave, but know they have a symbolic package too and can do such things. Thanks for that addition.

Comment: @Moo Kindly check my edit.

Comment: @Mark: That changed the problem a lot, but I added what $A^n$ is. That will take some work to work through cases, but you only need find a negative result for an entry. Maybe there is a slicker way.

Comment: @Moo Wolfram Cloud was really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @Mark: Glad I could help! Cheers!

Comment: Hello, @Moo!  I just saw your activity in the late answer queue, and thought of you.  I hope all is going well with you!

Comment: @amWhy: Great to see you back and in full swing!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. We may take $b=a$ and then for the matrix
$$
A=A(a,a)=\begin{pmatrix}0 &-1&-1&-1\\
-1& 0 &-1&-1\\
1&-1&0 &-1&\\
-1&0&-1&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
we see that $A^a$ is positive (all entries positive) if and only if 
$$
a=6k \quad \text{ for } \; k\in \Bbb N. 
$$
So we have infinitely many such $a$, and hence infinitely many such matrices.

Answer (score -1):

If you can diagonalize the matrix.  (Not all matrices can be diagonalized but most can)

$A = P^{-1}DP\\
A^2 = P^{-1}DPP^{-1}DP = P^{-1}D^2P\\
A^n = P^{-1}D^nP$

The diagonal matrix is easy to multiply by itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to deal with too many matrices at the moment and it is not possible to diagonalize each of them. I was aware of this method already. However, right now I'm looking to just speed up my process.